# Animated Div goes right and left, but not up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which i am trying to animate using jQuery.My goal is to move the div left,up,right and down based on the corresponding key presses.

E.g if i press the left arrow key, the div moves left etc etc.

Currently my div is able to move, left,right,up and down when then page loads/refreshes. HOWEVER, once i move my div right i am unable to move it left, when i move it down, i am unable to move it up and so on...

How would i make my div more smoothly in all directions?

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6U6cA/4/

**My code**

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="switcher">
        <div class="label">TestDiv</div>
        <button id="switcher-default">Default</button>
        <button id="switcher-large">Default 1</button>
        <button id="switcher-small">Default 2</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
#switcher {
  width: 300px;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.label {
  width: 130px;
  margin: .5em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#switcher').css({
  position:'relative',
  display:'inline-block'
});
$(document).keyup(function(event){
  var key=event.which;

  switch(key){
    case 37:
      $('#switcher').animate({right:'+=20'});
      break;
    case 38:
      $('#switcher').animate({bottom:'+=20'});
      break;
    case 39:
      $('#switcher').animate({left:'+=20'});
      break;
    case 40:
      $('#switcher').animate({top:'+=20'});
      break;

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're first setting the `left` style property, and then the `right`, but that doesn't work because `left` is not removed so it's overriding the `right` style.

Stick with one CSS property

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#switcher').css({
        position: 'relative',
        display: 'inline-block'
    });
    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        var key = event.which;

        switch (key) {
            case 37:
                $('#switcher').animate({
                    left: '-=20'
                });
                break;
            case 38:
                $('#switcher').animate({
                    top: '-=20'
                });
                break;
            case 39:
                $('#switcher').animate({
                    left: '+=20'
                });
                break;
            case 40:
                $('#switcher').animate({
                    top: '+=20'
                });
                break;

        }
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6U6cA/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just a qn though. From my console, i see that when using my code example, the div will end up with something like left:20px, right:40px, top:40px,bottom 60px. In this case, why wouldn't the left & right, top & bottom cancel each other out, leaving me the equivalent of right:20px, bottom:20px instead of the left property overriding the right?

Comment: Because you can't set both right and left (when the width is set), one has to win, and in this case it's left.